# Is there any java SDK for Oracle Messaging Server MTA SDK?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, communication, messaging

I have stucked when our client ask us to use java instead of C for enqueuing message in Oracle Message Transfer Agent. Till now we were following SDK reference and tutorials available on oracle web site .

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/CommSuite/MTA+SDK+Reference

Here the documentation and api's are available for C only But I can't find any SDK api's in  java.
Please let me know if there is any MTA's java SDK are available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Communications Suite is a standards-compliant mail server.  Use [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).